# how to use get function to pass an argument/parameter to a lambda function which is a value in the dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

To implement switch cases, people have suggested to use dictionary like:

`result = { 'a': lambda x: x * 5, 'b': lambda x: x + 7, 'c': lambda x: x - 2 }`

and call it using- `result['a'](2)`

But to set a default value, people have suggested to use get function. How do I pass 'a' and 2 as well as default value using get ?

This dosen't works: `result.get(['a'](2),default)`

Here 'a' is the key to be searched and if found 2 is the parameter for the lambda function. Default represents any value in case if key 'a' is not found.

Comment: `result.get('blah', lambda x: 0)(0)`

Comment: you title and content do not match. For default, use collections.defaultdict

Comment: @OlvinRoght thank u so much. But is there an option of setting default value by just writing the value and not the whole "lambda x" part ?

Comment: what is the value of default? this may be the issue

Comment: @JoelCompany, default could be any value, an integer ?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Why don't you post it as an answer (although in this case perhaps not using `get` is better)

Comment: @OlvinRoght Would definitely accept your answer if u post it. It's exactly the answer to what I meant to ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [*docs*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) of `dict.get()`:

> Return the value for *key* if *key* is in the dictionary, else *default*.

Values in you dictionary is callable which expect 1 argument, so we can pass *lambda* which will return `0`:

```py
result.get('blah', lambda x: 0)(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is `dict.get(key_to_find, default_return_if_key_not_found)`. In your example `"a"` is a key, and `2` is a parameter. Do you intend for this to be your default return value from this dictionary? If so:

```py
result.get(some_key, result["a"])
```

This will return the `lambda` associated with `some_key` if `some_key` is present, otherwise, will return the `lambda` associated with the key `"a"`. Of course it's not quite clear exactly *what* you're trying to define as your default return value from this dictionary.

If instead you are trying to give your `lambda` expressions default values for their parameters, you'd need to do something like `lambda x=default_value: return_value` for your `lambda` expressions.

Comment: Thank u so much. I understand the answer now. I am sorry for not framing the question properly, this is my first question on stackoverflow. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all add another parameter in the lambda like this:

```
result = {
'a': lambda x, y: x * y,
'b': lambda x, y: x + 7,
'c': lambda x, y: x - 2 
}
```

Then to call the function without 'result.get('blah', lambda x: 0)(0)'
Use:

```
result['a'](2, default)
```